# PROBLEMA BORRAR ELEMENTOS DE UN FRAME

Tags: python, clase, funcion

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en Python mediante el libro "Python Programming Fundamentals" de Kent D. Lee y resolviendo un ejercicio me ha surgido una duda de concepto.

En el ejercicio se pide que definamos un tipo de dato llamado **Clearable** (es decir, definir una clase) y que dentro de dicha clase designemos dos funciones:

-La primera función es la que tiene que ejecutarse por defecto (****init****) y se basa en crear una lista del tamaño que nosotros le asignemos, por ejemplo, escribiendo Clearable(10) generará dentro de la clase una lista de 10 elementos (en este caso los generé de elementos vacios).

- La segunda función, de nombre ****getitem**(item)** debe de buscar el valor que nosotros introduzcamos en la lista generada, si lo encuentra devuelve el número y si no lo encuentra devuelve **None**.

El problema lo que conseguido programar de la siguiente forma:

```
import sys
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
import os

class Clearable:
    def __init__(self,size):
        self.size = size
        self.lista = []
        for i in range(self.size):
            self.lista.append(i)
        print(self.lista)
    def __getitem__(self,item):
        encontrado = False
        for i in self.lista:
            if i == item:
                encontrado = True
                break
           
        if encontrado == True:
            return item
        else:
            return None
        
       
def main():
    elemento = Clearable(100)
    print(elemento.__getitem__(10))
    

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

El problema es que en el ejercicio estipula que si **cl** es una lista de tipo Clearable, al escribir **cl[item]** debe de ejecutarse el método **cl.**getitem**(item)** y no se cómo conseguirlo sin escribir **elemento.**getitem**(10)**.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

A continuación, y por si acaso, dejo el enunciado del ejercicio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Al igual que `__init__`, el cual es un método predefinido para un "constructor" de una clase, `__getitem__` también lo es. Mientras la función de "init" es ejecutarse automáticamente al crear un nuevo objecto de clase *, "getitem" automáticamente se encarga de ser llamado con corchetes, así como una lista.  No es necesario usar `obj.__func__()` para llamarles, no están hechas para ser llamadas directamente.

Answer (score 1):

Como dice el enunciado, debes utilizar `cl[item]` para recuperar el item:

```
def main():
    elemento = Clearable(100)
    print(elemento[10]) => 10
```

También

```
def main():
    elemento = Clearable(100)
    print(elemento[101]) => None
```

**Explicación**

`__getitem__()` es un *método mágico*, es la forma en como se implementa el acceso via `[]`. Cuando Python encuentra un `[]` aplicado a un objeto (como en `cl[item]`) lo que hace es buscar en la clase del objeto un método `__getitem__` y lo ejecuta pasando como parámetro el `item`.

Hay métodos mágicos para todo. Otro muy usado es `__str__`, que es llamado cuando Python necesita mostrar el objeto en forma legible para un humano.

Operaciones como la suma de objetos también se implementan con métodos mágicos (`__add__`).

Investiga y descubrirás un tesoro.